# How to use cron triggers in drone in addition to step conditions?

Tags: cron, drone.io

Say I have this drone.yaml file:

```
kind: pipeline
type: kubernetes
name: default

  - name: echo-hello
    image: alpine
    commands:
      - echo "hello"
    when:
      event:
        - push

  - name: echo-goodbye
    image: alpine
    commands:
      - echo "goodbye"
    when:
      event:
        - push
```

In addition to triggering the `echo-hello` and `echo-goodbye` step upon each push, I'd like to trigger all steps based on a cron event. I thought adding the `trigger` section to the bottom of the yaml file would do the trick:

```
trigger:
  event:
    - cron
  cron:
    - hourly
```

But then, it ignores the conditions defined beneath `when` in the dedicated steps. Can anybody help me fixing my drone.yaml file, so that I can trigger by cron in addition to the step specific conditions?

Answer (score 1):

Trigger mean that this whole pipeline will run only when cron runs it. You should add

```
event: 
  - cron
cron:
  - hourly
```

to `when:` for each section.

Comment: This does not work